# How to make page content Dynamic with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a database which contains more than table one of them authors and their names, jobs, social accounts, etc.

I need to make a static page template and a route for that page so if anybody clicks on that author name in the site, take all of his information's from the database table and showing them on the page.

In a different way, i need to make a function to handle the request if anybody clicked on that author to now more about him, thus, i have a different request every time including a different author .

I can do that line by line for each on of them but it sounds bad, because i don't want to end up with 1000 lines of code, there is alot of them out there inside the table .

Please any way to do that in clear way, as always any help would be really appreciated :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication with the base use:
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/

for templete Jinja2

Declaring Models base
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/

Sample code

```
@app.route('/author/<username>')
def show_user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    name = user.name
    last_name = user.last_name
    adres = user.adres
    return render_template('show_user.html', user=user, name=name, last_name=last_name, adres=adres)
```

Comment: That helped dude thanks alot @Ritero, but you know, all the authors i have them in Russians, is there any way to have them in a nice way in the link so for example: http://localhost:5555/authors/Ногинов, to be like http://localhost:5555/authors/Noginov.

I've seen before an article, they says by using `micawber` you can do stuff like this but unfortunately i can't find it !!